# Lua XML-RPC Base64 XML tag

Tags: wordpress, lua, base64, xml-rpc

So far as I can tell Lua XML-RPC does not include XML tag Base64 so transmitting binary data from a string type poses a problem.

I've hacked a workaround which intercepts the encoded message, flipping "string" to "base64" where the data is precoded base64, and with added line breaks to keep inside a sensible line length. This works with wordpress servers, the target.

Question: is this facility directly in Lua XML-RPC?

Refs.
http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Media

http://keplerproject.github.io/lua-xmlrpc/manual.html#data_types